# How to access a method from extending class in extended class?

Tags: java, class

I want to use/call a method inside `EdumateSuperClass` that I created in `Navigation` class. Is that possible? Anything I tried didn't work.

```
public abstract class EdumateSuperClass extends ScriptSuperClass

public abstract class Navigation extends EdumateSuperClass
```

- `super.clickNewButton();` --> The method clickNewButton() is undefined for the type ScriptSuperClass

PS Please update the title if necessary. Not sure if I used the right terminology.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "use a method inside `EdumateSuperClass` that I created in `Navigation` class". Can you show more code than just these headers?

Comment: I want to call this method inside a method. But I am getting an error because the method is not `visible`.

Comment: Please put things like this in your question. You can only access public methods, or protected methods if they are in the same package.

Comment: Can you add your method declarations and exactly what you are trying to call from where?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ... I used the word `visible` because it is my understanding why it doesn't work. I don't know if I am right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the method as abstract in the using class (or its parent classes), and implement it in the child class:

```
public abstract class EdumateSuperClass {
    protected abstract void childMethod(String message);

    public void callChildMethod() {
        childMethod("hello");
    }
}

public abstract class Navigation extends EdumateSuperClass {
    protected void childMethod(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply override an existing method.

Comment: I didn't get error in IDE after implementing your solution. I will test it and accept later. Thank youuuuu.

Comment: FYI this is generally referred to as the [Template Pattern](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java-Design-Patterns/Template/)

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** use `super` to call a method of `Navigation` from inside `EdumateSuperClass`.

`EdumateSuperClass` is the superclass of `Navigation`.

Your hierarchy is: `ScriptSuperClass` -> `EdumateSuperClass` -> `Navigation`, where -> indicates "base class of" or "super class of".

`Navigation` can use `super.X()` to call *concrete* methods of `EdumateSuperClass`, **not** vice versa.

When you're doing `super.clickNewButton()` from inside `EdumateSuperClass`, it's trying to call the method `clickNewButton` from inside of the base class `ScriptSuperClass`. This method is *undefined* for the class `ScriptSuperClass` and therefore that is why you get that specific error.

**EDIT:** If you wanted, you could have `EdumateSuperClass` remain an abstract class which declares an abstract method `abstractMethod()` and `Navigation` be a concrete class that defines a concrete implementation of this method.

You still **can't** use `super` from `EdumateSuperClass` to call this method inside `Navigation`, however this will allow you to use `EdumateSuperClass` as basically an interface when grouping objects.

ie. You could have an array of `EdumateSuperClass`, which means that this array can hold references of *concrete* class objects derived/extended from `EdumateSuperClass`. For these classes to be *concrete* they *must* define `abstractMethod()`. From there you can store `Navigation` objects in that array and call `abstractMethod()` from any element in that array.

However, that doesn't mean you're calling `abstractMethod()` from inside `EdumateSuperClass`, it'll still be a `Navigation` object that will contain the definition of `abstractMethod()` and be calling that from itself. I don't know if that makes it any clearer or not.

Read up on [polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: By doing `super.clickNewButton();` I was just trying a suggestion from @xthexder

Comment: Great explanation, I needed something like that. What about the original question?

Comment: @Radek I editted my post based on what I now think you might be asking. You can use `EdumateSuperClass` as the type of an array and group objects derived from `EdumateSuperClass`, such as `Navigation` objects, and call a method that `EdumateSuperClass` *declares* as abstract and `Navigation` *defines*. But in the end `EdumateSuperClass` still knows nothing about its subclasses, the same way `Object` knows nothing about any of its derived classes. This is known as polymorphism.

Comment: AusCBloke: Thank you for the explanation. I hoped you would tell me how to make it work as it is now and explain :-) I implemented @Inerdia's solution that works really smoothly.

Comment: @Radek Yeah I see what you're trying to do now (I think). However you're not necessarily calling a method of `Navigation` from `EdumateSuperClass`, you're just calling your abstract method and *any* concrete class that extends `EdumateSuperClass` will have an implementation of that method. I tried to explain something similar to that and why you were finding errors, but all in all good to see you got it working in the end.